Password not working on first login
I feel like I'm going crazy here.
I just downloaded and installed VM VirtualBox and Xubuntu to run on it.
I'm following The Odin Project so followed their instructions for setting up, which said to tick the box for unattended installation. At some point during the setup process I had to enter a username and password, password twice to confirm.
Having finally completed the install, it brings up the login box, with my username in the dropdown box.
I type in the password and it says its incorrect. I must have tried it 50 times.
I'm sure it's right.
I dug around in some files in one of the associated folders and found my username and password and it matched what I was typing.
I then rebooted in recovery mode to try and reset the password that way but it wouldn't let me type in root mode because it wanted a password. I eventually gave up and told it to restart normally, where it asked for my username and password before restarting, so I typed them in as before and they worked... But when it rebooted and the normal login box came up again it says it's incorrect.
Can anyone tell me how I can fix this so I can actually start using it?

"I dug around in some files in one of the associated folders and found my username and password and it matched what I was typing." Your password is not stored in plain text anywhere in a properly-installed Xubuntu system, so it is unclear what file you were looking at. "associated folder" suggests you were browsing your Windows system, which also should not have any record of your Xubuntu password (why would it?). Together, those clues suggests that you (somehow) did not follow the directions accurately. Start over, and don't skip any steps.

Yeah I think I might have to start over, I was just hoping for something I hadn't considered :/ I do think it's odd though that the username/password works in recovery mode so it must be correct but yeah I must have done something wrong somewhere. The files I "dug around in" are associated with the vm box setup so yes, within windows. But this is the only time I set a username and password, and the username is prefilled in the Xubuntu OS so it has to be related...

"...the username is prefilled in the Xubuntu OS" That seems like normal behavior. There is only one login account, the one you created. So there is only one choice.

Are your language/locale settings different between Windows and Xubuntu? If each OS thinks the keyboard is a different language, that would be one possible explanation. Common self-inflicted problem in some parts of the world.

I don't believe so, I can't see why the would be, and the worst it would be is English US/UK. I'm going to bite the bullet and uninstall/reinstall. And set a simpler password for the first login!

OMG you solved it for me! There's an option to view a keyboard on the screen, it's a slightly different layout to my physical keyboard so I used the pop up one and it worked! Thank you!
